# How to save and retrieve data from shared preference by input order?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

How to save and retrieve data from shared preference by input order in java?

When i save such data in shared preferences

```
 HashMap<Integer, String> likes = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    // THIS IS INPUT ORDER

    likes.put(1,"a")
    likes.put(2,"b")
    likes.put(3,"c")
    likes.put(4,"d")
        editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAM", 0).edit();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : likes.entrySet())
         editor.putString(String.valueOf((entry.getKey())), 
         entry.getValue());
        editor.apply();
```

when i retrieve it

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAM", 0);
    for (Map.Entry entry : prefs.getAll().entrySet()) 
           likes.put(Integer.valueOf(entry.getKey().toString()), 
           entry.getValue().toString());
```

it looks like

```
(1,"a")
(2,"b")
(4,"d")
(3,"c")
```

which not same input order!

Comment: Is this question about HashMaps or SharedPreferences?

Comment: Hash map are not ordered, if that matter, change collection type...

Comment: @PaulBoddington i have modified it

Comment: @Dreamer I saw. It's still a bit confused (I think your put statements have keys and values the wrong way around), but it's definitely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you want insertion order of keys or numerical order? Do the keys sometimes go into the map in an order like 1, 3, 4, 2?

Comment: @PaulBoddington try to make simple array list and store it shared preferences then retrieve using same "for"  that i used you will understand the problem

Comment: @PaulBoddington keys randomly order but unique as you see i convert each integer key to string as a key

Comment: @Dreamer Ok I understand. I'll try to come up with a solution.

Comment: @PaulBoddington will be very thankful for your help

Answer (score 1):

try the following 
`Map<Integer, String> likes = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();`
*LinkedHashMap* was designed for the purpose of keeping keys, values and entries in the order they were put in.

Comment: the problem is when retrieving data from  shared preferences hashmap not from Hashmap likes

Comment: How to convert shared preferences to LinkedHashMap? this is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` are designed for storing and retrieving simple data, and it is fairly awkward to use them for even slightly complicated structures.

You appear to be trying to store and retrieve a `Map`, and you want iteration order to be insertion order. Firstly, you should be using a `LinkedHashMap` rather than an ordinary `HashMap` because the latter doesn't make any guarantees about iteration order.

```
Map<Integer, String> likes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

However that isn't going to mean that the order is preserved when you get the data out of the `SharedPreferences`.

You could fix this by using keys `"K0"`, `"K1"`, `"K2"`... to store the map's keys and keys `"V0"`, `"V1"`, `"V2"`... to store the map's values. Something like this would work (not tested):

```
int index = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> e : likes.entrySet()) {
     editor.putInt("K" + index, e.getKey());;
     editor.putString("V" + index, e.getValue());
     index++;
}
```

Then to retrieve:

```
Map<Integer, String> likes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String, ?> all = prefs.getAll();
for (int i = 0; i < all.size() / 2; i++) 
    likes.put((Integer) all.get("K" + i), (String) all.get("V" + i));
```

This is obviously hideous, and `SharedPreferences` wasn't really designed for this, but it works.

Comment: I will try it and give you the answer but i have keys they start from  1 to 400 this will not make unique keys

Comment: @Dreamer Fixed!

Comment: Cannot define "get" in                likes.put((Integer) i.get("K" + i), (String) i.get("V" + i));

Comment: Are there other things in the SharedPreferences?

Comment: Nothing there , i have array that contains values and sequence of these valuse for example "wwewew","dsdsdsdsd","sdsdsds" the sequence is unique i used as key (starting from 1 to end of string array) , the value of string as value

Comment: Did you change `i.get` to `all.get`? `get` is definitely a method of `Map`.

Comment: From your comment about the array, it sounds like what you're really trying to do is store a `String[]` in a shared preferences. The whole `Map` thing was a complete red herring. My code definitely compiles as I just tried it. I think I'm going to give up on this one.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help , but the only way to fix this is retrieve elements from shared preferences using normal for and index of each set,else nothing work